# Andrews Plot random numbers in corner

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying trying to plot some country data in an Andrews Plot but the number '1e12' keeps showing up in the top right corner and I have no idea why its there or how to get rid of it. Here is the plot itself:

[image]

Here is the code I used to make it, pretty standard Andrews Plot:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas.tools.plotting import radviz
from pandas.tools.plotting import table 
from pandas import read_csv
from pandas.tools.plotting import andrews_curves
import os

filepath ="/Users/.../DefenseAndrews.csv"
os.chdir(os.getcwd())
os.getcwd()
dc = read_csv(filepath,
header=0, usecols=['Country','GDP','ME','GE','Trade','PopDensity'])

plt.figure()
andrews_curves(dc, 'Country')
plt.legend(loc='best', bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 4.3))
plt.savefig('figure4_AndrewsPlot.eps', format='eps', dpi=1200)
plt.show()
```

My previous solution was to just open save it and manually erase it in an art program. However, I now have to create the images as a eps file which I can't edit after the fact. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: please provide at least a snippet of your csv file

Answer (score 1):

That value is the scale on the axis.  You'll have to divide your data by a factor of about 1e11.  See the following example with iris data.

[iris data linked here](https://raw.github.com/pydata/pandas/master/pandas/tests/data/iris.csv)

```
from pandas.tools.plotting import andrews_curves

data1 = pd.read_csv('iris.csv')
data2 = data1.copy() 
data2.iloc[:, :4] *= 1e11

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10, 5))
andrews_curves(data1, 'Name', ax=axes[0])
andrews_curves(data2, 'Name', ax=axes[1])
```

[image]

You'll notice the left chart does not have this scale number while the right chart does.  I deliberately multiplied the data charted on the right by a factor of 1e11.